# How to update a column of sql table adding a variable to the current value in C#

Tags: c#, sql

Im using this code

```
updt = new SqlCommand("update dailysale set totalunit1 = totalunit1 - " + double.Parse(textBox3.Text) +" where material = '" + comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() +"' AND sn > '" + enmbr + "' ", agr, transac);
```

but this doesn't make update whereas

```
SqlCommand up2 = new SqlCommand("update dailysale set sn = sn +2 where sn > '" + enmbr + "' ", agr,transac);
```

is working for me

Comment: Use parameterized query. By the way, you are missing a **"** before **AND**

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: plz edit to my statement

Comment: I don't get any error msg but there no update is made

Comment: So it may be your where clause. In the first query you also filter on material

Answer (score 3):

Using a parameterized query avoid subtle syntax errors hidden in the string concatenation and prevent any possibility of Sql Injections

```
string cmdText = "update dailysale set totalunit1 = totalunit1 - @sold " + 
                 "where material = @mat AND sn > @emb";
updt = new SqlCommand(cmdText, agr);
updt.Transaction = transac;
updt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sold", Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text));
updt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mat", comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString());
updt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emb", embr);
int rowsUpdated = updt.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(rowsUpdated > 0)
   MessageBox.Show("Record updated!");
```

In your original text you miss the double quotes before the AND and *probably* the conversion of your textbox to a double introduces a decimal separator not understood by your database. Instead a parameterized query leaves the work to correctly quote the values to the framework code and your query text is no more obscured by the string concatenations and quoting

Comment: Just a typo with **@emb** and **@enb** ;)

Comment: Glad to be of help, however I wish to ask why you never accepted an answer?

Comment: @Sonu_Orai You have asked 19 questions in your 2 1/2 years as a member of StackOverflow, yet you have never accepted an answer to one of your questions.  Your reputation would actually increase by accepting answers that resolved your issue.  Be a good citizen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the result count?

```
if updt.ExecuteNonQuery() <> 0 Then
```

If it's zero then your where clause didn't select any records

If it's not zero then maybe you didn't commit your transaction.

```
transact.Commit()
```